# What happens if you travel faster than design speed rounding a banked curve?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I understand that the car would veer towards the outside of the curve.

I am confused about the next statement, which says that while the car slides up the slope, the car would actually be moving in a straight line according to Newton's 1st law.

Is this true? If $v > v_{\text{design}}$, the horizontal component of the normal force is less than the required frictional force and the car slides up the slope. However, isn't there still some force acting towards the centre of the circular path? Therefore, the 'no net external force' condition in Newton's 1st law is not satisfied, and the statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. When the car slides up (or down) the bank, the normal force, gravity and friction (if applicable) are still acting on the car, so the net force on the car is not zero, and it moves in a curve. It is just no longer moving along a *horizontal* curve.

Answer (score 1):

Driving around a banked curved requires a specific speed to match the curve radius:

$$a_c=\frac{v^2}r.$$

The centripetal acceleration towards the centre of the curve is caused by a matching force which in this case is a combination of static friction and normal force from the road.

- With a lower speed you won't be able to reach the required inwards centripetal acceleration. You might slide downwards, depending on how strong the friction is.
- With a higher speed, you are forcing a larger centripetal force. If the road is able to supply this force via static friction etc., then you will continue driving in the same curved path, just faster. But if you drive so fast that a higher force is required than what the road can exert, then friction will let go (and be replaced by kinetic friction) and your car will slide outwards, which means upwards, until a new, larger radius has been reached that matched the possible centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the net force will be considered equal until and unless friction force gripping the car is equal to centrifugal force and if a vehicle is going faster than the speed for which bank was designed for the centrifugal force will be greater hence car will slide upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.

The car "wants" to travel in a straight line (Newton's first law) but is not "allowed" to because there is a net force on it (Newton's second law).
That net force "makes" the car move along a curved path.
If the speed of the car increases then the net force is not large enough to maintain the same trajectory (curvature) and so the curvature of the path of the car must decrease.
The only way that the car can do this is to move further up the bank thus increasing the radius of the trajectory of the car.